# Integrating SharePoint online with external application using Microsoft Flow scheduler

Tags: power-automate

I need to integrate an external application with SharePoint Online where i need to retrieve data on a daily basis.
Was thinking of implementing it as a Microsoft Flow scheduler and using HTTP REST API action . Is this the right way or is there any other way ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Apart from it sounds rather like general question about some business process architecture, let's go through it:

> i need to retrieve data on a daily basis.

That's ok and what MS Flow is widely used for. You can list items/folders, create new ones or delete them and get file content.

> Was thinking of implementing it as a Microsoft Flow scheduler

This sounds like `Reccurence` trigger which runs an event at regular, customized time intervals.

> using HTTP REST API action

Indeed, `HTTP` action allows you to invoke REST API. On the other hand `When a HTTP request is received` trigger allows you to start the flow from other flow/app.